# Where is the mention of Jain tirthankars in Yajurveda?

Tags: vedas, other-religions, yajur-veda

According to wikipedia article on [Rishabhanatha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishabhanatha) -

> The Yajurveda mentions the name of three Tīrthaṅkaras –  Ṛṣabha, Ajitanatha and Arishtanemi, states Radhakrishnan, and "the Bhāgavata Purāṇa endorses the view that Ṛṣabha was the founder of Jainism".

Where is the mention of these Tirthankaras in Yajurveda?

Comment: Yajurveda predates Jainism. It is unlikely that you will find mentions of Jainism/Jain masters in the veda. It is possible that the names we see in the veda were used for latter-day Jain saints as well. For e.g., if I were to name my son Rama, it does not mean that he is Lord Rama although the hope is that he will emulate Lord Rama.

Comment: @moonstar i know! Just some Jains were claiming this so I thought why not recheck, yajur Veda is from satyuga afterall

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Regarding mention of the name of Rishabha .

The word Rishabha is used in Yajurveda for ram not for Tīrthaṅkaras. In [**Yajurveda Samhita 21.60**](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ZMQXBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT241&lpg=PT241&dq=rishabha%20in%20yajurveda&source=bl&ots=O4TKh2ENbF&sig=cwasNRxqGk6WCcUCptch4Kp7ivo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOhKvpnOvZAhUBObwKHY5cBFIQ6AEIVzAE#v=onepage&q=rishabha%20in%20yajurveda&f=false)  .According to some sources the actual name is Usabha and not Rishabha. The word Rishabha is used for ram many times in all four vedas.

> सुपस्था s अद्य देवो  वनस्पतिरभवदव्श्रीभ्यां छागेन सरस्वत्यै
>   मेषेणेन्द्राय **ऋषभेणा** क्षस्तान 
> मेदस्त: प्रति पचतागृभीषतावीवृधन्त
>   पुरोडाशैरपुरश्विना सरस्वतीन्द्र: सुमात्रा  सुरासोमान् |
>
> 60 To-day the divine Vanaspatî has done good service to the Asvins
>   with a goat, to Sarasvatî with a ram, to Indra with a bull. They have
>   eaten these from the marrow onwards, they have accepted the cooked
>   viands, they have waxed strong with the rice-cakes. The Agnis,
>   Sarasvatî, and Indra have drunk the Surâ and Soma draughts.

According to Hinduism [**Rishabha**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rishabha_(Hinduism))  is one of the twenty two avatars of Vishnu in the Bhagavata Purana.
Here is [**English**](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/wyv/wyvbk21.htm)  Translation.

---

## Regarding mention of the name of Ariṣṭanemi.

[**Ariṣṭanemi**](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Ari%E1%B9%A3%E1%B9%ADanemi) was one of the five sons of Vinatā and Kaśyapa, and a brother of the famous Garuḍa. Sometimes, the sage Kaśyapa himself has been known by this name.
The Pāṇḍava prince Sahadeva had assumed this name when he lived in Virāṭanagara, in disguise.

This whole mantra is from Y**ajurveda samhita 25.19**   and .Here we can see the meaning of Ariṣṭanemi

> स्वस्ति न इन्द्रो वृद्धश्रवाः  स्वस्ति नः पूषा विश्ववेदाः ।
>  स्वस्ति
>   नस्ताक्षर्यो **अरिष्टनेमिः** स्वस्ति नो ब्रुहस्पतिर्दधातु ।| [**YV 25.19**](http://literature.awgp.org/book/yajurveda/v2.76)||
>
> Swasti Na Indro Vriddhashravah  Swasti Na Poosha Vishwa-Vedaah  Swasti
>   Nastaaksharyo Arishtanemih Swasti No Brihaspatir-dadhaatu
>
> May God Indra of Great fame bless us , May the Omniscient Poosha bless
>   us  ,**May the Protector Garuda bless us** ,May Lord Brihaspati
>   protect us

---

## Regarding mention of the name of Ajitanatha .

The [**wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajitanatha) itself say that - "The Yajurveda mentions the name of Ajitanatha, but the meaning is not clear."

According to [**this**](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Jain_Dharma#cite_note-37) site Ajitanatha is mentioned in  Yajurveda 25, 19 and 9, 25

---

In conclusion there is no trace of tirthankaras in Yajurveda. only the similar names . And the meaning of those names in vedas are different.

Comment: I think they have different meanings and may not be names of Jain Tirthakaras.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Yes you are right the meaning is totally different. Stated that in conclusion . :-)

Comment: Yes. Saw now. Good answer, btw.